# Checking existence of a non-crossing Hamiltonian path in geometric graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

I am interested in the following computational problem. Given a geometric graph (i.e, a graph drawn in the plane so that its vertices are represented by points in general position and its edges are straight-line segments connecting the corresponding vertices), check whether the  graph admits a non-crossing Hamiltonian path (i.e. there exists a path in the graph that covers all the vertices but does not intersect itself). Are there any hardness results (or efficient algorithms) known for this problem?

References, if any, on the above problem will be appreciated. The only reference that I am currently aware of is [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X06004318), but I don't think it addresses the above problem directly.

Comment: This quite recent paper may help: Eppstein, David. "Non-crossing Hamiltonian Paths and Cycles in Output-Polynomial Time."  arXiv:2303.00147 (2023).